Go Integration Tests Code Coverage with sonarqube
I am using go cover to generate the coverage profile.
reference: https://go.dev/doc/build-cover
I want to integrate the report with sonarqube
go tool covdata textfmt -i=somedata -o profile.txt

using this a text format coverage profile would be generated after running the integration tests. How would this be integrated with sonarqube.
